# Mediawiki multiple languages are not working (Extension:Translate)

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

We made a Company mediawiki for documentation etc. Now i wanted to set the translate Extension and itself ist working in the way, that it´s showing up.

I have my article

"Lorem Ipsum"

If i set like suggested

< translate >
"Lorem Ipsum"
< /translate >

The message with translating is coming. But if i want to write and select now another language, i can´t choose it. I installed it like it was in the instructions:

```
wfLoadExtension( 'Babel' );

wfLoadExtension( 'cldr' );

wfLoadExtension( 'CleanChanges' );
$wgCCTrailerFilter = true;
$wgCCUserFilter = false;
$wgDefaultUserOptions['usenewrc'] = 1;

wfLoadExtension( 'LocalisationUpdate' );
$wgLocalisationUpdateDirectory = "$IP/cache";

require_once "$EXT/Translate/Translate.php";
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['translate'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['translate-messagereview'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['translate-groupreview'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['translate-import'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['pagetranslation'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['translate-manage'] = true;
$wgTranslateDocumentationLanguageCode = 'qqq';
$wgExtraLanguageNames['qqq'] = 'Message documentation'; # No linguistic    content. Used for documenting messages

wfLoadExtension( 'UniversalLanguageSelector' );
```

(Source: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_Language_Extension_Bundle and
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:Translate/Installation)

There is only my Default language and not the languages i should choose with cldr. I´m totally stucking

Comment: There is a dropdown in the upper right corner of the translation interface for selecting which language you want to translate into.

Comment: exactly this Dropdown menu is not working. there is only my default language